# Is there a way to set a MKAnnotationViews callout to auto resize?

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkannotation, core-location, mkannotationview

The problem I'm having is I'm doing reverse geocoding and the full address is getting cut off in the callout. Is there any way to set autoresizingsubviews to YES?

Thanks

Nick

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use your own custom annotation and calculate the size. As far as I know the default style will not support what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Tho not necessarily a good idea, you can play with the subviews of the annotation view directly.

The annotation view itself has only one subview: the callout. That subview has it's own subviews. Explore them to find what you need, or play directly with the callout view.

In the following example I update the callout subtitle directly. The subtitle UILabel is the 7th item in the callout subviews:

```
if (myAnnotationView.subviews.count > 0)
    ((UILabel*)[((UIView*)[myAnnotationView.subviews objectAtIndex:0]).subviews objectAtIndex:7]).text = @"Some example";
```